# OS X Lion: app.log file in Applications Folder

Tags: macos

I noticed a file 'app.log' in my Applications folder. I delete it but it reappears after a couple of days. What is this and can I get rid of it?

Comment: Open Terminal.app and type `less /Applications/app.log`. This should display the file content which might contain hints about where it is coming from.

Comment: @patrix: +1, don't know why didn't I think of that :-)

Answer (score 2):

Probably a bit sledgehammer-to-crack-a-nut, but if its happening fairly regularly and you can't figure out what's creating it another way, you could start a terminal prompt and leave the following command running

```
sudo opensnoop | grep -i app.log
```

This will monitor for `app.log` being created and tell you the process that created it (I'm assuming there won't be that many processes creating a file called `app.log`, but I guess you could narrow it down to `/Applications` if you wanted to). At least then you'll be armed with the knowledge of what is creating the file and can potentially do something about it.

For example, whilst running the above command, if you type

```
touch app.log
```

in another terminal tab or window, the original one running the `opensnoop` command displays

```
501  10576 touch          3 app.log              
501  10099 mdworker       6 /Users/binarybob/Documents/app.log
```

Comment: Great! Just tried it. Thanks for the opensnoop and touch commands. I learnt something new again :) I got the following results:  
    `dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 4 (ID 1436: syscall::open:return): invalid user access in action #4 at DIF offset 0
    dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 4 (ID 1436: syscall::open:return): invalid user access in action #4 at DIF offset 0
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 4 (ID 1436: syscall::open:return): invalid user access in action #4 at DIF offset 0`

Comment: sorry about the formatting I tries using the mini markdown formatting but id doesn't seem to work in comments :/

Comment: @pechar: Regarding those errors, did you have iTunes running at the same time? Several online forums report that dtrace throws this error if it is.

Comment: No iTunes was not on for sure I only had the browser running. @binarybob

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys I just found out what is generating this file. Its a log file for exceptions caused by an application called FreeRapid.app which is a download helper like JDownloader. Thanks to both @patrix and @binarybob for the help